# Is this valid in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

This doesn't bring up any errors but I wanted to know if this is valid in GraphQL. I'm using useQuery and I pass in a list of strings. Origionally I wanted to use useState and pass in a variable with a true/false value of weather it was in the list or not but due to the rules of hooks I can't do that I guess. SO what I did was use the include directive to see if a string is in the list passed in as a variable. Does this work?

```
query ContentQuery(
    $stringList: [String!]!
  ) {
        ...welcomeImageFragment
          @include(if: "STRING", in: $stringList)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@skip` and `@include` directives only take a single argument (`if`) whose type is `Boolean!`. The argument only accepts `true`, `false` or a variable whose type is also `Boolean!`.

If you want to conditionally include some field or fragment based on some arbitrary condition, you should declare a variable of the type `Boolean!` and then set the value of the variable to the condition.

If you want to not execute the query at all, you should use the `skip` option of the hook instead.